# Is there a way to extend my class but still use the parent class as reference for functions in c++?

Tags: c++, class, extend

I made a class Position, it has a tuple inside of it (the position) and some functions. I use this class in most of my other classes.
Now i want to create a child class MovingPosition which shall add some functions, but no new variables.
Now i want to use my MovingPosition class at the same occasions i used my Position class before.

This is a theoretical question to increase my knowledge, i don't really need it for an active project of mine since i can (and in this project i currently want to) code around that problem.

Lets say i got my two classes:

```
class Position{
   public:
      tuple<int,int> pos;
   ...
};
class MovingPosition : public Position{
   ...
};
```

and lets say i have a function:

```
printObj(Position pos);
```

and now i want to do this:

```
MovingPosition mPos;
printObj(mPos);
```

Can i just use my MovingPosition var at the same place i ask for a Position var? And if i can't is there a way to do just that?

Comment: MovingPosition is derived from Position and you are accepting the base type therefore yes, you can use a derived class when the base class is accepted, its called PolyMorphism.